# How to write INTERVAL MINUTES and CURRENT TIMESTAMP in MySQL function ?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, function

I am working for migrate DB2 to MySQL queries . I have following query to convert to MySQL .

**DB2 Query :**

```
CREATE FUNCTION SAMPLE_TEST
  (
    IN CONNECTED TIMESTAMP,
    IN DISCONNECTED TIMESTAMP,
    IN INTERVAL BIGINT
  ) RETURNS INTEGER
  DETERMINISTIC
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION
  CONTAINS SQL
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT
  BEGIN ATOMIC
    IF (CONNECTED IS NULL) THEN
        RETURN -1;
    ELSEIF (DISCONNECTED IS NULL) THEN
        RETURN CASE WHEN (INTERVAL = 0 OR CONNECTED + INTERVAL MINUTES > CURRENT TIMESTAMP) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
    ELSE
        RETURN CASE WHEN (INTERVAL = 0 OR CONNECTED + INTERVAL MINUTES > CURRENT TIMESTAMP) AND CONNECTED > DISCONNECTED THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
    END IF;
  END#
```

I have tried to convert the following query to MySQL and i am getting INTERVAL  as error in MySQL . This is the final converted query .

**MySQL query :**

```
CREATE FUNCTION SAMPLE_TEST
  (
    CONNECTED TIMESTAMP,
    DISCONNECTED TIMESTAMP,
    INTERVAL BIGINT
  ) RETURNS INTEGER
  BEGIN
    IF (CONNECTED IS NULL) THEN
        RETURN -1;
    ELSEIF (DISCONNECTED IS NULL) THEN
        RETURN CASE WHEN (INTERVAL = 0 OR CONNECTED + INTERVAL MINUTES > CURRENT TIMESTAMP) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
    ELSE
        RETURN CASE WHEN (INTERVAL = 0 OR CONNECTED + INTERVAL MINUTES > CURRENT TIMESTAMP) AND CONNECTED > DISCONNECTED THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
    END IF;
  END;
```

Here i am getting error on `INTERVAL BIGINT` and

```
RETURN CASE WHEN (INTERVAL = 0 OR CONNECTED + INTERVAL MINUTES > CURRENT TIMESTAMP) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

should i write `CURRENT TIMESTAMP` to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in MysQL ? Any help to solve this problem ? Any documentation ?

Comment: in MySQL it's indeed CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: What does `+ INTERVAL MINUTES` mean?

Comment: I have already declared `INTERVAL BIGINT` but i am getting error on INTERVAL  also .

Comment: MySQL uses  this format `[[date|datetime]] + INTERVAL [number] [SECOND|MINUTE|HOUR|DAY|MONTH|YEAR]` with INTERVAL.. this might help you out.

Comment: I am trying to return the  TIMESTAMP .  if the total time stamp > current timestamp , i am return 1 . else 0

Comment: I am adding any 'time' to a timestamp

Comment: `CONNECTED + INTERVAL MINUTES` , means i have declared some values in   `CONNECTED TIMESTAMP,INTERVAL BIGINT` and i am adding this tboth time